References for topological rings and completions for a topological rings
Recently, I am reading some papers about cluster algebras and representations about quantum affine algebras. In these papers, authors often use some topological rings and completions for a topological ring, such as the following question link A question about completion of a ring with the given topology.
This question is also asked by me. I am not familiar with it.
I want some reference books or notes on topological rings and completions for topological rings.
Thanks!

In this article they construct completion using equivalence classes of Cauchy nets, so its appropriate for structures such as topological rings

As a general introduction to topological rings, also covering completions, you might consult the two books of Seth Warner: "Topological fields" (!989) and "Topological rings" (1993). Of course, the latter might be more appropriate for you. But I doubt that they contain as specific topics as mentioned in the question you linked to. I haven't found an online version, but each university library should have them..

The article I've linked above uses the concept of "conet". I believe this is only because they consider quasi-uniform spaces. Also, they don't touch upon size issues, if that bothers you.

@Ulli The 1993 edition can be found on certain sites of questionable legality

These are answers to the question, not just a comment. Please notice that comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, I suggest to post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.
